# Display Scroll Reveal Animation after each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollreveal.js

I'am using this template: https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/ with the plugin jQuery Scroll Reveal

If you look at this page: https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/#services

The animations (Dimond, paper plane, newspaper and the heart) are loaded after each other. Icon numer 2 starts to animate when numer one are finished etc.

When I'am trying to do the same thing are all animation loaded at the same time.

JavaScript (just added `.sr-step` to the template)

```
// Initialize and Configure Scroll Reveal Animation
window.sr = ScrollReveal();
sr.reveal('.sr-icons', {
    duration: 600,
    scale: 0.3,
    distance: '0px'
}, 200);
sr.reveal('.sr-button', {
    duration: 1000,
    delay: 200
});
sr.reveal('.sr-step', {
    duration: 600,
    delay: 200
});
sr.reveal('.sr-contact', {
    duration: 600,
    scale: 0.3,
    distance: '0px'
}, 300);
```

And this is my html

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 sr-step">
                            <h3 class="step-number">01</h3>
                           <div class="step-text"><p>Text text text text.</p>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 sr-step">
                        <h3 class="step-number">02</h3>
                       <div class="step-text">Text text text text.</div>
               </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 sr-step">
                        <h3 class="step-number">03</h3>
                       <div class="step-text">Text text text text.</div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 sr-step">
                    <h3 class="step-number">04</h3>
                 <div class="step-text">Text text text text.</div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

During the sequencer overhaul, it became clear that optional nature of the `interval` parameter was unnecessarily confusing. It now lives with all the other options.

```
// v3
window.sr = new ScrollReveal();
sr.reveal('.tile', { reset: true }, 16);

// v4
ScrollReveal().reveal('.tile', { reset: true, interval: 16 });
```

[source](https://scrollrevealjs.org/guide/whats-new.html)

Answer (score 0):

Found the delay on `200`

```
sr.reveal('.sr-icons', {
    duration: 600,
    scale: 0.3,
    distance: '0px'
}, 200);
```